# Reading from a dictionary in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a piece of code were it asks for your name and score, then saves your most recent scores to a csv file. I have managed to get it to check if you are in the dictionary and store your 3 latest scores in a the csv file. However, I do not know how to get the code to open the file which it is saved in, meaning after every time the dictionary is saved it just has your latest store and deleting everything else.

This is what I have got:

```
import csv

nam=input("Name")
sco=int(input("Score"))


if nam in class1:
    namsco=class1[nam]
    del class1[nam]
    del namsco[0]
    namsco.append(sco)
    class1[nam]=namsco
    print("Score added")
else:
    print ("Creating profile")
    class1[nam]=[0,0,sco]
    print("Score added")


with open('temp.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, class1.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(class1)
```

I left out `class1={}` because that would need to be added when the dictionary is imported.

Comment: serious question: why `nam` instead of `name`, why `sco` instead of `score`? Also if you're trying to serialize ("save") a `dict` object, why are you doing it with `csv`? Is this a problem of interoperability? If not, why not pickle it instead?

Comment: Open file in `append` mode instead of `write` mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following tries to initialize the `class1` dictionary with the data in the csv file. If this fails because it's the first time and the file doesn't exist, it's set to an empty dictionary.

Next it updates this dictionary by either adding a new entry or updating an existing one, and then at end rewrites the entire file with the values from the updated dictionary.

Note that when using `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter`, each row is also a dictionary. In this case it might have been easier to use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` where each row is just a sequence of values.

```
import csv

name = input('Name: ')
score = int(input('Score: '))

try:
    with open('class1.csv', 'r', newline='') as inf:
        class1 = {row['name']: [row['score0'], row['score1'], row['score2']]
                    for row in csv.DictReader(inf)}
except FileNotFoundError:
    class1 = {}

print('Updating' if name in class1 else 'Creating', name+"'s", 'profile')
del class1.setdefault(name, [0, 0, 0])[0]
class1[name].append(score)
print('Score added')

with open('class1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outf:
    FIELD_NAMES = ['name', 'score0', 'score1', 'score2']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, FIELD_NAMES)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(dict(zip(FIELD_NAMES, [name] + scores))
                        for name, scores in class1.items())
print('File written')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the 'a' argument (appends to the file), instead of 'w'.

Comment: Almost, I want to be able to open the file so I can change the oldest value, not just add them to the file again. For example, I want to open Sue's score and change it from 4,1,5 to 1,5,7. Not created another Sue with 0,0,7.

Comment: Open the file, read the data, change the value, write to a new file.  Your original question was very misleading.  It seemed as though you wanted to continually append data into this file.  What you actually want to do is essentially create a new file with your changed values.  You can overwrite the original but there is no editing a csv file in place.